# Mean of this alert message box in Android

Tags: android-emulator, alert

I am creating a simple application in Android.  When I compile and run it in the emulator, it's showing an alert box like this; what it does mean?

**sorry, The application simplegame (process com.example.simplegame) has stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again!**

I'm getting this alert box always?  Please explain?

UPDATE:

just trying to import a Picture in it,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;



public class SimpleGame extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Bitmap mBackGroundImage;
    private Canvas canvas;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBackGroundImage = hBitmapFactory(R.drawable.background1);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackGroundImage, 0, 0,null);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    private Bitmap hBitmapFactory(int background1) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

am newable to android.thats why getting some troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your application is crashing, there must be some exception in your app. Please check the log .

Comment: . Thank u for the quick reply...I checked it clearly and i havent any errors in my log...

Comment: can you write few codes that what actually you are doing in the app.

Comment: If your trying to import a picture do it simply in main.xml , why you are trying to make the code so complex. Its a wrong approach to do this .

Comment: good...i feel it was complex...you're correct its simple in main.xml